# Maximal ideal $M$ of $R[x]$ gives prime $M\cap R$ of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Intuition tells me that this is true but I am not sure how to prove this.

Attempt:
If $M$ is a maximal ideal then $R[X]/M$ is a field. Suppose $M\cap R$ was not prime. Then $R/M\cap R$ is not an integral domain. So there is some $a,b$ non zero such that $ab=0$. But now we can consider these $a,b$ in $R[X]/M$. This contradicts $R[X]/M$ being a field.

Comment: Hint: if $i : R \hookrightarrow R[x]$ is the canonical inclusion map, then what is $i^{-1}(M)$?

Comment: as far as I understand $i^{-1}(M)=R\cap M$? maybe I'm missing something obvious but im not sure how that helps

Comment: Well, in general, any inverse image of a prime ideal by a ring homomorphism is again prime.

Comment: is this hard to see or where would I find a reference for this?

Comment: The ‘proof’ just consists in applying the definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general result:

> Let $f:A\longrightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings, and $\mathfrak q$ be a prime ideal in $B$. Then $\mathfrak p=f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ is a prime ideal in $A$

Indeed $f$ induces an injective homomorphism
$$\bar f:A/f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)\longrightarrow B/\mathfrak q.$$
Now, if $\mathfrak q$ is prime, the quotient $B/\mathfrak q$ is an integral domain, and $A/f^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$ is isomorphic to a subring, which, necessarily, is also an integral domain.